# Camel xml splitter header support

Tags: xml, apache-camel

I am using Camel XML splitter to split an ONIX file which is basically XML. It also contains a header that I need to send along with each split message. How can I do this which camel xml splitter? Also how can i make the camel xml tokenizer case insensitive?

Here is the ONIX xml file.

```
<ONIXMessage>
<Header>
<FromCompany>HarperCollins Publishers India</FromCompany>
<FromPerson>Richard Collogan +61 2 9952 5522</FromPerson>
<FromEmail>richard.collogan@harpercollins.com.au</FromEmail>
<ToCompany>HarperCollins Publishers India</ToCompany>
<SentDate>201312241110</SentDate>
</Header>
<Product>
<RecordReference>9788172238475</RecordReference>
<NotificationType>03</NotificationType>
<ProductIdentifier>
<ProductIDType>02</ProductIDType>
<IDValue>8172238479</IDValue>
</ProductIdentifier>
<ProductIdentifier>
<ProductIDType>03</ProductIDType>
<IDValue>9788172238475</IDValue>
</ProductIdentifier>
<ProductIdentifier>
<ProductIDType>15</ProductIDType>
<IDValue>9788172238475</IDValue>
</ProductIdentifier>
<ProductForm>BC</ProductForm>
<ProductFormDetail>B105</ProductFormDetail>
<NoSeries/>
<Title>
<TitleType>01</TitleType>
<TitleText>The White Tiger Pb</TitleText>
</Title>
<Website>
<WebsiteLink>
http://www.harpercollins.co.in/product.asp?isbn=9788172238475
</WebsiteLink>
</Website>
<Contributor>
<ContributorRole>A01</ContributorRole>
<PersonNameInverted>Adiga, Aravind</PersonNameInverted>
<KeyNames>Adiga Aravind</KeyNames>
</Contributor>
<NoEdition/>
<BICMainSubject>FA</BICMainSubject>
<BICVersion>2</BICVersion>
<OtherText>
<TextTypeCode>02</TextTypeCode>
<Text textformat="02">
<![CDATA[
Winner of the Man Booker Prize 2008 Meet Balram Halwai, the &#39;white tiger&#39;: servant, philosopher, entrepreneur, murderer&#38;hellip; Born in a village in the dark heart of India, the son of a rickshaw puller, Balram is taken out of school and put to work in a teashop. As he crushes coal and wipes tables, he nurses a dream of escape. His big chance comes when a rich landlord hires him as a chauffeur for his son, daughter-in-law, and their two Pomeranian dogs. From behind the wheels of a Honda, Balram sees Delhi and begins to see how the Tiger might escape his cage. For surely any successful man must spill a little blood on his way to the top? The White Tiger is a tale of two Indias. Balram&#39;s journey from the darkness of village life to the light of entrepreneurial success is utterly amoral, brilliantly irreverent, deeply endearing and altogether unforgettable.
]]>
</Text>
</OtherText>
<OtherText>
<TextTypeCode>13</TextTypeCode>
<Text textformat="02">
<![CDATA[
Aravind Adiga was born in Madras in 1974. He studied at Columbia and Oxford universities. A former India correspondent for Time magazine, his articles have also appeared in publications including the Financial Times, Independent and the Sunday Times. His first novel, The White Tiger, won the Man Booker Prize in 2008 and was shortlisted for the John Llewellyn Rhys Prize, as was his short-story collection Between the Assassinations (2009).
]]>
</Text>
</OtherText>
<MediaFile>
<MediaFileTypeCode>04</MediaFileTypeCode>
<MediaFileLinkTypeCode>01</MediaFileLinkTypeCode>
<MediaFileLink>
http://www.harpercollins.co.in/image.asp?isbn=9788172238475
</MediaFileLink>
</MediaFile>
<Imprint>
<ImprintName>HarperCollins</ImprintName>
</Imprint>
<Publisher>
<PublishingRole>01</PublishingRole>
<PublisherName>Harpercollins Publishers</PublisherName>
</Publisher>
<PublishingStatus>04</PublishingStatus>
<PublicationDate>20091103</PublicationDate>
<SalesRights>
<SalesRightsType>01</SalesRightsType>
<RightsCountry>IN PK LK BT MV BD NP</RightsCountry>
</SalesRights>
<Measure>
<MeasureTypeCode>08</MeasureTypeCode>
<Measurement>309</Measurement>
<MeasureUnitCode>gr</MeasureUnitCode>
</Measure>
<SupplyDetail>
<SupplierName>HarperCollins Publishers India</SupplierName>
<ProductAvailability>21</ProductAvailability>
<Stock>
<OnHand>500</OnHand>
<OnOrder>0</OnOrder>
</Stock>
<Price>
<PriceTypeCode>01</PriceTypeCode>
<PriceAmount>350.00</PriceAmount>
<CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>
<CountryCode>IN</CountryCode>
</Price>
<Price>
<PriceTypeCode>01</PriceTypeCode>
<PriceAmount>5.62</PriceAmount>
<CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
<CountryCode>PK LK BT MV BD NP</CountryCode>
</Price>
</SupplyDetail>
<MarketRepresentation>
<AgentName>HarperCollins Publishers India</AgentName>
<AgentRole>07</AgentRole>
<MarketCountry>IN PK LK BT MV BD NP</MarketCountry>
<MarketPublishingStatus>04</MarketPublishingStatus>
<MarketDate>
<MarketDateRole>01</MarketDateRole>
<Date>20091103</Date>
</MarketDate>
</MarketRepresentation>
</Product>
</ONIXMessage>
```

Comment: In what form do you want to add the header information in the XML to the split message? As exchange headers? Or part of the exhange body? I don't know if you can make the tokenizer work case-insensitive, but I would not be surprised if you cannot. XML is a case sensitive (meta) language. IMO to use a tokenizer that is not would be wrong.

Comment: It is not clear how the ONIX message has to be split. Some code what you already tried would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

These might give you the pointer -

http://www.davsclaus.com/2011/11/splitting-big-xml-files-with-apache_24.html
http://www.davsclaus.com/2011/11/splitting-big-xml-files-with-apache.html